# Two Roll Dicer Java object-oriented way

Tags: java

Hi I am new to Java OOP and I have some problems in running the program

The problem is there is no output and the loop never stops.

This is my Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dice firstDie = new Dice();
        Dice secondDie = new Dice();
        do {
            count++;
            if(firstDie==secondDie ){
                same=true;
                System.out.println("It took "+count+ " times " + firstDie.getValue() + " and " + secondDie.getValue());
            }
        }
        while(!same);
    }
}
```

and this is my Dice.java

```
public class Dice {
    private int value;
    public Dice() {
        value = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
    } public int getValue() { return value; }

}
```

in my Main.java class when I write int count = 0; and boolean same = false; the loop never ends.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the wonderfully frustrating world of computer programming. One of the skills you need to learn along the way is debugging your code when it doesn't work quite the way you expect or want. For some tips on doing this, read [this great article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). After you do so, come back with more questions including what you learned while debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have to compare the value `firstDie.getValue()` and `secondDie.getValue()`.

What you are trying to do is compare the 2 instances of class `Dice` . When you compare those, unless they are the same object, it cannot be same.
Hence, `same` is not made true at all and this goes to a loop.

For more info, please refer, `equals()` method in java because that is what is called when two instances/objects are compared.

Edit:
Even if you try below code snippet of do-while (ie. compare the value `firstDie.getValue()` and `secondDie.getValue()`,

```
do {
            count++;
            int first = firstDie.getValue();
            int sec = secondDie.getValue();
            System.out.println(first+ " "+sec);
            if(first==sec ){
                same=true;
                System.out.println("It took "+count+ " times " + first + " and " + sec);
            }
        }
        while(!same);
```

It still goes to loop because of the fact that the `value` of `Dice` class is set only once i.e. in constructor.
So the ideal way is to write,

```
public Dice() {
        value = 0;
    } public int getValue() { return (int)(Math.random()*6)+1; }}
```

Comment: @Alexis,  please check now.

Comment: @Alexis, is this still going to loop?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the classe's instances and not the values stored within them.
Notice that on your println you are referring to each of the dices values (which is what you want to compare and have match), but on your comparison you are checking the objects.

Since they are 2 different instances they will never match, and therefore there will be no output and the loop never stops.

Answer (score 0):

try `firstDie.getValue() == secondDie.getValue()` instead of `firstDie== secondDie`

You are checking for the two instances to be equal if you say `firstDie== secondDie`. These two are never equal.

Comment: How can we use `firstDie.value` if `value` of `Dice` class is private?

Comment: so in my Dice.java class I have to set `private int value` to public

Comment: @Alexis, that is not an elegant solution as it defeats the purpose of OOP concept called as `Encapsulation`.

Comment: i didnot see it is private...made changes